# Checking if a point is inside or outside a polygon for an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to be able to check if a user inputted point is inside or outside a bounded set of points.I am aware of the .contains function for the Polygon class in java, but I was wondering how I would go about doing something like that for an ArrayList of < Point > .

Here is an example of what I'm trying for:

The points of the polygon are:
(-10, 0)
(-1, -10)
(0, 10)
(1, -10)
(10,0)

Test point:
5 0

> Inside

Test point: 8 8

> Outside

Any hints in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Are the points always given in consecutive order ?

Comment: Yes they are I can sort them to be in the same order every time.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a little homeworky, so I am not going to go into great detail, but assuming that the polygon points listed are always in order, you could connect lines between all the points in the polygon to close its border, then cast rays from your sample points outward. If the ray passes through an odd number of lines before going outside the area the polygon is in, that means the sample point is inside the polygon. If it passes through an even number of lines, it is outside the polygon. (If it never goes through a line, it is also outside the polygon, assuming the ray is long enough to hit the edge of the polygon from where the sample point is located.) Best of luck.

[More Information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)

Comment: Right, I'm not asking for code just a push in the right direction. I'll look into ray casting, but it looks like it's way over my head at this point. I appreciate the response though!

Comment: You're welcome - there are many other ways to accomplish your goal as well, but casting rays is my favorite for that particular problem, from an effort/reliability perspective. It may not be as hard as you think. (Hint: if you can make a line, you can make a 'ray' to an arbitrary point outside the polygon.)

Comment: Are the polygons guaranteed to be convex? Can you guarantee the points are in order around the edge of the polygon? If so, a fast solution involves iterating through each pair of neighbouring (clockwise or counterclockwise) and ensuring the clockness from p to pA pB is always the same or colinear (in other words, you're ensuring the test point is always on the correct side of a half-plane). You're stepping into legit computational geometry otherwise - if so, have fun!